# Display Dashboards in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I am not able to display Standard salesforce dashboard in visualforce. i tried with this code. but not able to achieve this.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false"> 
       <apex:iframe src="https://cs10.salesforce.com/01ZJ00000000N2n?isdtp=nv" 
                    scrolling="true" 
                    height="1588px" width="100%"/> 
</apex:page>
```

I have gone through some of the sites. they said that with Clickjack Protection  i-Frame does not support in vf pages. so what should i do now? is there any other solution for this.

Please help me..

Comment: Srinivasa, could you show us what you've tried and how that isn't working ?

Comment: Please update the question with more info, that'll make it easier to also explain what you were doing.  + that's easier for others to see the full question in a single location.

Comment: Samuel De Rycke  i added the code. can you please check once.

Comment: Here is a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/IBQcywsJ0OE) that should help you out.

Answer (score 3):

In Summer 14 Release Salesforce released the Analytics Dashboards API. With this you can easily integrate dashboard data into any web or mobile application, inside or outside the Salesforce platform.

[Salesforce.com Summer ’14 Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_analytics_dash_api_introduce.htm)